# Avoid duplicates while using itertools combinations - python

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, permutation

So I have a dictionary with index keys looks like :

'00' : 'Value1'

'01' : 'value2'

.....

'99' : 'value 100'

Im trying to get all possible combinations of key-value by using this :

```
        for i in range(2, 7):
        for x in combinations(sorted(KEY_DICT.keys()), i):
            code = ''
            value = ''
            for k in x:
                code += k
                value += f'{KEY_DICT[k]}, '
            dic = {code: value}
            comb_dict_list.append(dic)
            pprint(comb_dict_list)
```

But there is a problem, it's creating duplicates like

0199

9901

But I need only unique values, skiping strings like in example above, how can I do this ?

Comment: No, `combinations` won't produce `9901`. Ever. Not unless you have duplicate `01` or `99` entries.

Comment: What is `k` in the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a problem, `itertools.combinations()` produces combinations that are unique *in any ordereding*, exactly as you already wanted. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

> Elements are treated as unique based on their position, not on their value. So if the input elements are unique, there will be no repeat values in each combination.

and the source code example given:

```
# combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD
```

Note that there is no `BA`, because `AB` is already generated.

Concretely, for your example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> [''.join(combo) for combo in combinations(['01', '99'], 2)]
['0199']
```

Only `'0199'` is produced, `'9901'` will never be produced.

As a side note, you don't need to call `dict.keys()` when sorting keys. `sorted(KEY_DICT)` will do just fine, as iteration over the dictionary produces keys too.

Comment: Thank you  for explanation )